# Increment a Byte in an IP address

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Really simple thing I want to do in Ansible ... or so you would think.

All I want to do is to set a variable [which I later use in a j2 template] to the value of `ansible_default_ipv4.network`, with the last byte chopped off and third incremented.

so, if `ansible_default_ipv4.network` is 192.168.10.0, I want to the new variable set to 192.168.11.

Here's how I presently do it:

```yaml
- set_fact:
   x: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network.split('.')[0:3] }}"
- set_fact:
   x2: "{{ x.2 | int  + 1 }}"
- set_fact:
   x3: "{{x.0}}.{{x.1}}.{{x2}}"
```

Works fine, but is as ugly as a box or frogs :(

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an [ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) which can be used to manipulate things involving IP address, netmask and the likes. This may be of interest to you.

Comment: This will produce 256.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        x: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network|ipmath(256)|splitext|first }}"
```